# Angular 11 switchmap not working after catch error

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I have two dropdowns in my angular app. Second one is populated based on first dropdown value. I am using switchmap. It works fine as long as there is no error. As soon there is no values to populate second dropdown and there is an error, subsequent call is not happening when i change values in first dropdown. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Here is my code:

```js
private customListItems$ = this.auditFilterService.subjectType$     // this is first option value
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    filter(x => x && x !== ''),
    switchMap((selectedSubjectType) => {
      const result = this.customListsService.getCustomListItemsByTypeName({
        typeName: selectedSubjectType,
        onlyActive: true
      } as CustomListItemsByLocationParams);
      return result;
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      console.log('error', err);
      return of(undefined);
    })
  );
```

Comment: Pipe in a `tap({ complete: console.log('complete') })` _after_ the `catchError` to check if the subscription is getting closed by the `of(undefined)` returned from `catchError`. Consequently you could try returning [`NEVER`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/NEVER) constant instead of `of(undefined)`.

Comment: You should put catchError in your inner stream. In switchMap instead of {return result} do this {return result.pipe(catchError(err => {...}))}.

Answer (score 5):

*Mulkil Deepthi*'s answer is correct but I would like to explain why it's important to catch the error from the inner observable inside `switchMap` (this is also relevant for others operators like `mergeMap`, `concatMap`).

In `RX`, an error means the Observable has **terminated** with an error, so you won't receive more elements from it.

This is well explained in the [`ReactiveX documentation`](https://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) :

> OnError 
> indicates that the Observable has terminated with a specified error condition and that it will be emitting no further items

> Observable termination 
> When an Observable does issue an OnCompleted or OnError notification, the Observable may release its resources and terminate, and its observers should not attempt to communicate with it any further.

The [`catchError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) doesn't prevent the subscription termination from the source observable, it just map the error to a new observable and subscribe to it. 
After the error occurs, you will only receive notifications from the observable returned by `catchError` (no more items will be received from the source observable because the subscription is terminated).

Here is a good example from the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) :

```js
of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .pipe(
    map(n => {
      if (n === 4) {
        throw 'four!';
      }
      return n;
    }),
    catchError(err => of('I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V'))
  )
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
  // 1, 2, 3, I, II, III, IV, V
```

`5` is never received because an error is thrown while mapping `4`
The observable returned by `map(...)` emits `1 2 3` and terminates with the error `four`
`catchError` handles it and subscribes to a new observable containing these elements `I II III IV V`

Coming back to your initial example :

```js
this.observable$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(value => this.createObservable(name)),
    catchError(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return of(undefined);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

If the observable returned by `switchMap` emits an error, the subscription will be considered as terminated, so you won't receive more elements. `catchError` map this error to a new observable which will produce `undefined`.

The observable returned by `switchMap` must not emit an error if you want to maintain the initial subscription.

You must catch the error inside the `switchMap` :

```js
this.observable$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(value => 
      this.createObservable(name).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          console.log(error);
          return of(undefined);
        })
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

In this example, the observable returned by `switchMap` will never produce an error because of the presence of the `catchError`. 
Note that you can also use `empty()` instead of `of(undefined)` if you don't want to emit any value.

Answer (score 3):

Following fix suggested in the comment by **munleashed** solves my issue:

```ts
  private customListItems$ = this.auditFilterService.subjectType$.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    filter((x) => x && x !== ''),
    switchMap((selectedSubjectType) => {
      const result = this.customListsService
        .getCustomListItemsByTypeName({
          typeName: selectedSubjectType,
          onlyActive: true,
        } as CustomListItemsByLocationParams)
        .pipe(
          catchError((err) => {
            console.log('error', err);
            return of(null);
          })
        );
      return result;
    })
  );
```